# How can I find all the trunks from several different Subversion servers?

Tags: svn

We have many SVN Repo's but many of them have nested projects.  I need some way of finding the trunk directories only and creating a list of them.

So, the svn path to trunk might be svn://svnserver/repos/myproject/trunk or it might be svn://svnserver/repos/myproject/mysubproject/trunk

I need to generate a list of /trunk directories from several different servers.  Is there a method for doing that?  Has anyone seen a script (sh, perl, whatever) for doing something similar? I just need a hint on how to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about spidering the web interface? This works:

```
httrack -q https://user:password@example.com/svn/ -O /tmp/svn -c1 -J1000 -t -%k -F HTTrack/3.0x -z -C0 -I0 -p0 -#T
grep trunk /tmp/svn/hts-log
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Unfortunately, httrack isn't installed and I haven't found a precompiled version for RHEL 2.6.9.  I tried compiling it but apparently don't have enough skill to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to look at the repos on the servers or the working copies?

When I've had to do this with a bunch of working copies, I just look for directories with .svn subdirectories then run `svn info` in each of them. I collate the results. I've never bothered to make a tool out of it though.

Comment: The repos on the server.  There are too many of them and they're too large to pull them all into working copies.   Thanks for the idea though.